# Need help in debugging a function to get the XY of a character in an array

Tags: c#

My current code is as follows:

```
public Position getXY(string sym)
{
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    var lines = _draw.GetBackground();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i].Equals(sym))
                goto End;
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    End:          
    return new Position(x, y);
}
```

The Position class is from Roy-T.Astar, a pathfinding library (it's used here to store coordinates).

The function will only output the maximum X and Y values in my array, and never pinpoint the character I am looking for.

Comment: *"The function will only output the maximum X and Y values in my array, and never pinpoint the character I am looking for."* That's probably because the method takes a `string` and not a `char`. Even if you pass in a single character as you input string, you won't find a match:  `'m'.Equals("m") == false;`

Comment: How do you expect `string sym` to ever be equal to `line[i]` (a character)? And for Pete's sake, get rid of the 1980's style `goto`. If your teacher told you do use it, find a new teacher. If the book you're reading said to use it, buy a better book.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Because the question doesn't say it's anything but a string. `foreach (string line in lines)` clearly says it's the former, not the latter.

Comment: @KenWhite Oops, my bad, didn't read that foreach! Nevermind me

Comment: @KenWhite yeah my apologies for that, had a 'break' but wanted to try something different, albeit worse, to enure that was not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking in a `string` argument, and then comparing each character of each line with that string to try to find a match. In this case, passing a string to the equals method of a char will call the overload that takes an `object`, and it will always return `false`.

To fix this, you can either take a `char` as your input argument:

```
public Position getXY(char sym)
```

Or you can do a string comparison:

```
public Position getXY(string sym)
{
    var lines = _draw.GetBackground();

    // lines.Length assumes a lines is a string[]
    for (int y = 0; y < lines.Length; y++)
    { 
        var matchIndex = lines[y].IndexOf(sym);

        // If the index is > -1, we found a  match
        if (matchIndex > -1)
        {
            return new Position(matchIndex, y);
        }
    }

    // It was not found, so return something that indicates that...
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And not a `goto` in sight. :-)